# How to make installshield limited cancel installation if framework 4.5 is not present?

Tags: c#, installshield

I'm using visual studio 2013.
I've tried enabling .net framework in the project assistant

[image]

But tried to install in 2 older computers with xp (and checked if network 4.5 was installed using https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-check-what-version-of-microsoft-net-framework-is-installed-in-computer/)

And the result is that on both 4.5 .net framework was not installed, and my installer ran without canceling.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but if you require .NET 4.5, you can uncheck XP and 2003. .NET 4.5 isn't available for those systems.